# Why did the Nazis invent videotelephony?

Tags: nazi-germany, technology

This claim [that the Nazis invented two-way video telephony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Videophone#World.27s_first_public_videophone_service:_Germany_1936.E2.80.931940) is astonishing and I almost thought it was a hoax. Except it's not, because it's copiously referenced to contemporary sources.

So other than propaganda, why did the Nazis build it? It's a major achievement, but was it actually worthwhile compared to an equal investment in phone lines or other forms of telecommunication?

Secondly, did anyone pick up on the research and technology for this service, which was revolutionary at the time?

Comment: How do you define "actually worthwhile" or "*absolutely* revolutionary"?

Comment: If you take a look at the article you see many company names, claims about it being open to the public and dates earlier than 1933. So I'd say that the answer is a) They didn't (Granted I did not check for political alignment of the inventors) and b) for business and pleasure (Edit: The source noting propaganda measures doesn't work so I wasn't able to read that)

Comment: Worthwhile... did it generate revenue greater than an equivalent investment in more humdrum telephone services would have? Revolutionary in that it brought something into public use, which would not be mainstream again until the 21st century

Comment: According to Wikipedia, the poster is correct: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_videotelephony#World.27s_first_public_videophone_service:_Germany_1936.E2.80.931940

Comment: AFAIK a 1920s German film Metropolis features a videotelephone.

Comment: The second question is much more interesting.

Comment: @Semaphore: I edited the question to take out the superlatives. I think the "core" question is OK.

Comment: "Why"? Because science/technology progresses. But as @Lohoris says- second question- why it did not continue to develop- that's a more interesting question.

Comment: @Rajib I think that's a little more existential than the OP intended.  The first question is asking about their practical plans for the invention, whether it was meant to be the first of a large vidphone network or just a stunt.

Comment: @Nerrolken Progress/discovery/invention is always an accident, not a stunt.

Comment: I would guess it was mainly a "stunt" for the 1936 Summer Olympics. Sources mention a network between Berlin, Munich, and Nuremberg (the site of the olympics) whose operation was shut down in 1940.

Comment: I'd question whether it was in fact a "major achievement", and whether it's anything like "mainstream" today.  Sure, it's pretty simple to do these days, but how many people bother?

Comment: I didn't think of it at the time, but this is a great way to get out of a family zoom call. 'Huh, you know who invented zoom? Yeah, the Nazis!'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So other than propaganda, why did the Nazis build it?

I'm going to narrow this down to *why did the Nazi government invest in a nationwide videotelephony service* because discussing whether each person/company/organization was "the Nazis" is another question.  Also because it's easier to trace to motivations of building a system requiring a large investment than a few people inventing a cool prototype *FÜR WISSENSCHAFT!*

I'm sure people came up with all sorts of ways it could be used that read like a sci-fi novel, [same as how the Internet was supposed to change our lives *in 1993*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5MnQ8EkwXJ0), but found out the hard way it was too soon and too impractical.  But propaganda value is the real reason.  The Nazi govt was all about showing the world Germany had recovered from the (in the Nazi view) humiliation of WWI, that it was a world power again, and that Fascism was the better way.  The 1936 Olympic games in Munich was televised.

> It's a major achievement, but was it actually worthwhile compared to an equal investment in phone lines or other forms of telecommunication?

No.  Like many inventions before and during WWII, it was too early.  Too expensive and too impractical with the immature technology.  And once the country went on war footing, they needed the money to blow things up.

Things would advance quickly and ten years after the network was shut down we'd have ubiquitous TV sets.  Ironically, [AT&T was predicting ubiquitous video phones in 1993](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5MnQ8EkwXJ0#t=0m48s) and they were *still* decades early.

> Secondly, did anyone pick up on the research and technology for this service, which was revolutionary at the time?

I don't know what was done with the network, but [the Germans developed a number of guided weapons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_German_guided_weapons_of_World_War_II) and experimented with television guidance.  The [Henschel Hs 117](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henschel_Hs_117) and [Hs 293D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henschel_Hs_293#Variants) were both TV guided, but fortunately the war ended before they could be perfected and put into production.

> An interesting development of the missile system was the Hs 293 D . It was a standard HS 293 A1 missile with an extended nose and fuselage center, build to carry Television equipment, thereby removing the need for the carrier plane to keep line of sight to the target. In the rear section of the missile was an antenna sending signals to the carrier plane. The television equipment, K11, was crude compared to todays guided weapons, 224 line pictures been screened at a frequency of 50 pictures a second. Test flight were carried out in 1944, but the development program never really took off. The TV guiding by Joystick required quite some skill from the operator, and for the program to work there needed to be a large amount of simulator training. Range for the TV signal was about 4 km.

[Source](http://www.1jma.dk/articles/1jmaluftwaffegroundweapons.htm)